# Replacing keywords with similar content

Tags: php

With a list of keywords like in the array below:

```
$keywordlist = array(
    'Apple iPhone' => 'http://www.example.com/apple/iphone/',
    'Apple iPad' => 'http://www.example.com/apple/ipad',
    'Samsung Galaxy Ace' => 'http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-ace',
    'Samsung Galaxy Nexus' => 'http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-nexus',
    'Samsung' => 'http://www.example.com/samsung/',
    'Apple' => 'http://www.example.com/apple/'
);
```

I want to replace the keywords with the URLs associated with them.

I've tried looping through them and use `str_replace` and `preg_replace`, but this is replacing the manufacturers name in all keywords, so all the keywords get turned into links for just 'Samsung' and 'Apple'. I'm a bit stumped as to where to head next, anyone got any pointers?

**Edit:**

I used the below code to loop through -

```
foreach($keywordlist as $name => $link){ 
    $content = str_replace($name, '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$name.'</a>', $content);
}
```

**Solution:**

I believe the problem was the link text I was replacing. It was then being replaced again by the other phrases with similar keywords, I've got the below to work.

Anyone think of a better way of doing this?

```
$content = "<p>This Apple iPhone is from Apple</p>
            <p>This Apple iPad is from Apple</p>
            <p>This Samsung Galaxy Ace is from Samsung</p>
            <p>This Samsung Galaxy Nexus is from Samsung</p>
            <p>This is a Samsung</p>
            <p>This is an Apple</p>";



$keywordlist = array(
    'Apple iPhone' => '[1]',
    'Apple iPad' => '[2]',
    'Samsung Galaxy Ace' => '[3]',
    'Samsung Galaxy Nexus' => '[4]',
    'Samsung' => '[5]',
    'Apple' => '[6]'
);

$content = str_replace(array_keys($keywordlist), array_values($keywordlist), $content);

$urllist = array(
    '[1]' => '<a href="http://www.example.com/apple/iphone/">Apple iPhone</a>',
    '[2]' => '<a href="http://www.example.com/apple/ipad">Apple iPad</a>',
    '[3]' => '<a href="http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-ace">Samsung Galaxy Ace</a>',
    '[4]' => '<a href="http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-nexus">Samsung Galaxy Nexus</a>',
    '[5]' => '<a href="http://www.example.com/samsung/">Samsung</a>',
    '[6]' => '<a href="http://www.example.com/apple/">Apple</a>'
);

$content = str_replace(array_keys($urllist), array_values($urllist), $content);

echo $content;
```

Output:

This [Apple iPhone](http://www.example.com/apple/iphone/) is from [Apple](http://www.example.com/apple/)

This [Apple iPad](http://www.example.com/apple/ipad/) is from [Apple](http://www.example.com/apple/)

This [Samsung Galaxy Ace](http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-ace/) is from [Samsung](http://www.example.com/samsung/)

This [Samsung Galaxy Nexus](http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-nexus) is from [Samsung](http://www.example.com/samsung/)

This is a [Samsung](http://www.example.com/samsung/)

This is an [Apple](http://www.example.com/apple/)

Comment: Can you show me, how you tried looping through the list. The problem with the unwanted replacing is due to same keywords being used multiple times in different keywords.

Comment: Have edited to show the code I used in the loop, thanks

Comment: You dont need to loop through the list. You could use `array_keys` and `array_values` to write a condensed statement. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should be enough for what you are attempting.

```
foreach($keywordlist as $key => $link) {
     $content = str_replace($key, '<a href="$link">$key</a>', $content);
}
```

As, I have commented, this will not work as expected because of the repeated duplicate keywords on the keys.

You need to have a fixed format to denote a key. The one I suggest is something like `[Apple]` and `[Apple iPad]`. When you implement something similar to this, every keyword will be different, although they contain same inner code inside.

Your updated keyword structure will look something this, after wards.

```
$keywordlist = array(
    '[Apple iPhone]' => 'http://www.example.com/apple/iphone/',
    '[Apple iPad]' => 'http://www.example.com/apple/ipad',
    '[Samsung Galaxy Ace]' => 'http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-ace',
    '[Samsung Galaxy Nexus]' => 'http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-nexus',
    '[Samsung]' => 'http://www.example.com/samsung/',
    '[Apple]' => 'http://www.example.com/apple/'
);
```

If this, options is not feasible to use, as this significantly increase the complexity while developing the content, as needing to wrap every keyword text with `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is the code I was using to loop through, but as there are repeated words within the keywords, it replaces that code twice (or more dependent on keywords!)

Comment: @Samson, You question is about replacing keywords, so it will be dependent on keywords. I will propose a different alternative.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, unfortunately I do not have control over what is typed so putting the keywords in tags is not really an option. Thrustmaster's solution below almost works, but as soon as I try to output any <a> tags around the content (e.g. 'Samsung Galaxy Nexus' => '<a href="http://www.example.com/samsung/galaxy-nexus">Samsung Galaxy Nexus</a>'), it seems to recreate the problem again.

Comment: @Samson, Thrustmasters's solution is basically the same thing. Its a shortcut of using `foreach`

Comment: I think I've come up with a suitable way of doing this. The problem seems to come when I create the URL, the link text is then being replaced again. So if I replace initially with my own unique key for each keyword and then use that key to replace the URL with link text back in, it should prevent the problem I think. Will paste it up when I have it working.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a little useless to me, since you have the same keys as values. Maybe I misunderstand your intentions.
But here you go: This makes the keys the same as the values (url's)

```
$newkeywordlist = array_combine (array_values($keywordlist),array_values($keywordlist));
```

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Same keywords will definitely problem during loops.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
$s = "this is a test";
$arr = array(
   "this" => "THIS",
   "a" => "A"
);

echo str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr),$s);
```

OUTPUTS:

```
THIS is A test
```